# Why does FSCK run even if you never have unclean shutdown?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, fsck

AFAIK `FSCK` checks and repair the file system in an event of an unclean shutdown like power failure (I'm not sure). I have a server that never had unclean shutdowns but still FSCK ran at some point after some months. Is FSCK really needed even if you never had unclean shutdowns?

Answer (score 2):

[`man 8 tune2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) actually answers both your questions:

> **-c** *max-mount-counts*
>
> Adjust the number of mounts after which the filesystem will be checked by [***e2fsck***](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)(8). If max-mount-counts is 0 or
>   -1, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by [***e2fsck***](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)(8) and the kernel.
>
> Staggering the mount-counts at which
>   filesystems are forcibly checked will avoid all filesystems being
>   checked at one time when using journaled filesystems.
>
> You should strongly consider the consequences of disabling
>   mount-count-dependent checking entirely. Bad disk drives, cables,
>   memory, and kernel bugs could all corrupt a filesystem without marking
>   the filesystem dirty or in error. If you are using journaling on your
>   filesystem, your filesystem will **never** be marked dirty, so it will not
>   normally be checked. A filesystem error detected by the kernel will
>   still force an fsck on the next reboot, but it may already be too late
>   to prevent data loss at that point.
>
> See also the **-i** option for time-dependent checking.

‮

> **-i** *interval-between-checks[d|m|w]*
>
> Adjust the maximal time between two filesystem checks. No suffix or **d** will interpret the number
>   *interval-between-checks* as days, **m** as months, and **w** as weeks. A value
>   of zero will disable the time-dependent checking.
>
> It is strongly
>   recommended that either **-c** (mount-count-dependent) or **-i**
>   (time-dependent) checking be enabled to force periodic full [***e2fsck***](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)(8)
>   checking of the filesystem. Failure to do so may lead to filesystem
>   corruption (due to bad disks, cables, memory, or kernel bugs) going
>   unnoticed, ultimately resulting in data loss or corruption.

---

As for finding the frequency of checks (after the *max-mount-counts* or the *interval-between-checks* thresholds) set on your own ext2/ext3/ext4 file system, you can run this command:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/YOURDEV | grep -Ei '(mount count|interval|check)'
```

Replace `/dev/YOURDEV` with the partition you want to examine.

Sample output:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/nvme0n1p3 | grep -Ei '(mount count|interval|check)'
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Mar 15 13:30:00 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is FSCK really needed even if you never had unclean shutdowns?

That depends.  Can you guarantee with 100% certainty that you will never have *any* data corruption in the storage system below the filesystem?

As a general rule, a filesystem check is functionally mandatory after an unclean shutdown on certain filesystems (older ones specifically, most commonly ext4), but an unclean shutdown isn't the only situation that can cause the filesystems internal data structures to become corrupted.  Non-catastrophic device failures (bad sectors, bad firmware, etc) can cause the exact same type of corruption, so it generally is a good idea to check every now and then even if your system doesn't crash or lose power.

This is particularly important with ext4 because:

- When using journaling (if you don't know if you are or are not using journaling, you probably are), the filesystem may never get checked otherwise, because a journaled filesystem is assumed to be self-consistent even after an unclean shutdown.
- The default behavior when encountering errors in the filesystem metadata at runtime is to simply log the issue and continue as if nothing happened.  THis means that compared to other filesystems (for example, XFS, BTRFS, or ZFS), it's much less likely that you'll notice if there's an issue with the filesystem until it's too late to fix it.